# I want to modify this program so the values would calculate when i perform an operation instead of pressin equals button

Tags: javascript

This is is a basic javascript calculator and it works fine but i want to modify it so operations would always perform and update instead of me clicking the equals button.

what i mean is when i do something like 2+2+2+2 it does not calculate until i press the equal button.

```
<div class="container"  >
<br>
<h1><B><font color="red" style= "font-size:70"> Ayoola's Calculator </font>     </B></h1>
<form name="calculator" >
   <input name = "display" placeholder="0" style= "width:254px; height:60px; 
      text-align:right; font-size:30; border-radius:8px; margin:3px"/>
   <br>
   <input name = "answer" placeholder="0" style= "width:254px; height:60px; text-align:right; font-size:30; border-radius:8px; margin:3px"/>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value= "7" name="seven"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='7'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; margin:3px"/>
   <input type="button" value= "8" name="eight"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='8'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "9" name="nine"   onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='9'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "*" name="multiply()" onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='*'" style="width:60px;  font-size:30; "/>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value= "4" name="four"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='4'" style="width:60px; font-size:30;  margin:3px"/>
   <input type="button" value= "5" name="five"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='5'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "6" name="six"   onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='6'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "-" name="minus()"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='-'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value= "1" name="one"   onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='1'" style="width:60px; font-size:30;  margin:3px"/>
   <input type="button" value= "2" name="two"   onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='2'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "3" name="three" onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='3'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "+" name="plus()"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='+'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value= "." name="point"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='.'" style="width:60px; font-size:30;  margin:3px"/>
   <input type="button" value= "0" name="zero"   onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='0'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "/" name="divide()"  onClick="document.calculator.display.value+='/'" style="width:60px; font-size:30; "/>
   <input type="button" value= "=" name="equal"  onClick="document.calculator.answer.value=eval(document.calculator.display.value)" style="width:60px;  font-size:30; "/>
   <br>
   <input type="reset" value= "C"   onClick= "clear()" style="width:256px;  font-size:30; margin:3px "/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the expression only on `click` of **"="** button.
You need to evaluate the result on `click` of each valid button after appending the value.

To provide you with some clue on how to proceed, you can create a common function which
  - takes button value as input,
  - appends that value to existing expression on input
  - and then evaluates the expression.

Comment: can you please explain with a code. am new to this  @madcap

Comment: @chev i need your help on this

Answer (score 0):

In generally it is considered better to set all event listeners in a script rather than inline and eval is typically discouraged. Ignoring that though, I would suggest changing the onclick of each button to a function such as

```
<script>
    function buttonHandler () {
        document.calculator.display.value += this.value;
        if (/[0-9]/.test(this.value)) {
            document.calculator.answer.value=eval(document.calculator.display.value);
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value= "7" name="seven"  onClick="buttonHandler.call(this);" style="width:60px; font-size:30; margin:3px"/>
...
```

**EDIT**
Changed onclick attribute to `buttonHandler.call(this)` to get a proper `this` for each function call. You can see it in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny5ntc9t/5/)

Comment: i have done this already but now there is no action. my numbers are not even displayed in the text box.. @joel

Comment: I changed the onclick attribute to be `buttonHandler.call(this)` and it worked for me in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny5ntc9t/5/)